# Notification after subscription through authorize.net

Tags: notifications, authorize.net

I am a developer and set up authorize.net for subscription. Suppose I subscribed for 12 months from January. I can get transaction id and payment status and other necessary information on January or after first payment. But how can I get the transaction id and payment status and other necessary information on 2nd, 3rd, 4th payment and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be notified of payments and retrieve all of the relevant information about them in an automated fashion use their [Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/) functionality. It is like Paypal's IPN as it will post transaction information to your website so you can record it in your database in real time.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this information inside Authorize.Net Merchant Interface : https://account.authorize.net

Under the

```
Recurring Billing
```

option, inside the

```
Transaction Status Report
```

page you will find the

```
Monthly Transaction Status Dashboard
```

which contains the Subscriptions transaction details

There is also an **ARB Email Notifications** options to get this transactions in email, under the `Recurring Billing` option